# Stop click event from firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, addeventlistener

I have 2 seperate event listeners, the first one is a click event, second one is a window beforeunload listener:
This is the click event listener:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click',function(event){  
if (event.defaultPrevented) return;
console.log('click EL');
})
```

and this is the beforeunload listener:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('beforeunload EL');
})
```

Can I stop the click event from firing if the beforeunload is fired? I've tried doing it with `event.preventDefault();` still it didn't work.

Comment: try e.stopPropagation();

Comment: @Frenchy it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, This is working code:

```
var beforeunload = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('beforeunload EL');
}

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", beforeunload);

document.body.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    if (event.defaultPrevented) return;
    console.log('click EL');
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", beforeunload);
});
```

Just remove the listener if your click happened

Comment: it didn't work, also I just want the listener to not be fired.

Comment: @AhmedMhadhbi yes can you try this, once you will click window will remove beforeunload and it will not fire this. I have tested this and found cool, I f you looking any other scenario let me know